# How to call registerForRemoteNotifications for both iOS7 and iOS8 in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6-beta6

*** Note this question is NOT how to register for remote notifications in swift, My question is how to write code in swift that will work when run on devices running both iOS8 and iOS7. The code I posted used to do that with Xcode beta 1 to 5 but with beta 6 now generates a linker error. So my question is how to change things to get around the new linker error in beta 6. ***

I'm getting the following link error with Xcode Beta 6

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"__TFSsoi1oUSs17_RawOptionSetType_USs21BitwiseOperationsTypeSs9Equatable__FTQ_Q__Q_", referenced from:
      __TFC12My_cWireless11AppDelegate29registerForRemoteNotificationfS0_FT_T_ in AppDelegate.o
```

For the following code which used to compile/link/execute without problem on Betas 1 to 5.

```
      func registerForRemoteNotification()
        {
            let registerForRemoteNotificationsMethodExists = UIApplication.sharedApplication().respondsToSelector(Selector("registerForRemoteNotifications"))
            if  registerForRemoteNotificationsMethodExists
            {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication()?.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
            else
            {
                // Fall back to using iOS7 as the code is not running on an iOS 8 device
 UIApplication.sharedApplication()?.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert)
            }
        }
```

Why has it stopped linking with the latest Beta? Is there a problem with the code which has been revealed with Xcode Beta 6?

Comment: The usual question: Have you tried "Clean Build Folder ..." (opt-shift-cmd-K) ?

Comment: Yes that makes no difference, nor does deleting the derived data.

Comment: Give [this](http://thatthinginswift.com/remote-notifications/) article a read and see.

Comment: Thanks but I already know that. My question is not how to register for remote notifications in swift. My question is how to write code in swift that will work when run on devices running both iOS8 and iOS7. The code I posted *used* to do that with Xcode beta 1 to 5 but with beta 6 now generates a linker error. So my question is how to change things to work with Beta 6.

Comment: This code works as of now with GM.

Answer (score 4):

First, check the iOS version number. Then, set the push notification for each version, respectively. I did have to 'clean' my build folder as well using opt-shift-cmd-K as Martin R suggested to resolve the linking error.

Here is my final code:

```
// Check to see if this is an iOS 8 device.
let iOS8 = floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
if iOS8 {
    // Register for push in iOS 8
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
} else {        
    // Register for push in iOS 7
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert)
}
```

Reference for checking the iOS version - http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/09/17/swift-ios-version-check/

Comment: You should check if UIApplication responds to certain selectors, do not depend on iOS versions. Following is a much better implementation: 

`if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar working in Objective-C:

```
if (registerForRemoteNotificationsMethodExists) {
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
    }
```

This complies in Xcode 6 B5. Haven't tried B6 yet.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to do it in Obj-C, my question is attempting to find the Swift equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the recommended way to check iOS versions in Swift 2:

```
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil))
    } else {
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert, UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge, UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound])
    }
```